# printf("%s", array); does not print anything

Tags: c, arrays, printf, character

Could you please explain why the array "reversed" specifically where I've **bolded** the text? Here is what's printed (with an input of "hi there"): "THE LINE (hi there) IN REVERSE:".

Also, the print statement within the for loop prints it as "reversed array: ?ereht ih-" in the final iteration.

Thank you!

```
int reverseit(int length, char line[]); // Function declaration 
#define MAXLENGTH 1000

int main()
    {
        int length = 0;
        char line[MAXLENGTH];       // array declaration
        gettheline(length, line); 
        ...
    }

void gettheline(int length, char line[])    
    {
    int i, c = 0;
    while((c=getchar())!= (EOF))
        {   
            if (c!='\n')            // we'll put the newline character in place ourselves when print in reverse is complete
                {   
                    line[i] = c;    // until you see \n, keep setting each char to line[i]
                    printf("line[%d]=%c\n", i, line[i]);
                    i++;            // increment i
                    length = i;
                }
            else if(i>0)            // else if c is == \n and i>0 , reverse it, and put \n at the end
                {
                                    // store reverse of the line and stick \n at the end
                    reverseit(length, line);
                }
    }

int reverseit(int length, char line[])  // pass in "length" from getline
    {
        int i, j = 0;
        char a;
        char reversed[length];
        for (i=length;i>-1;i--)         //count down from length to 0
            {   
                reversed[i] = line[j++]; 
                printf("line[%d] = reversed[%d] = %c\n", i, j, line[i]);
                printf("reversed array: %s", reversed);
            }
            **printf("THE LINE (%s) IN REVERSE: %s", line, reversed);**
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Umm... Where the heck are you filling `line`? You need some type of input function (`fgets`, `scanf` (discouraged), `getline` (POSIX))?? OK, I see by your **edit** the `...` are supposed to indicate you are taking input somewhere? See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **edit2 = much better.

Comment: length = 0;  is a problem.   reversed[i] = line[j] => reversed[j++]=line[i];  printf( "reversed array ..." ) should appear outside for() loop.  We need to see entire code to help you further.

Comment: @Nguaial, thanks for the j++ relocation tip. Revised that. Still cannot print reversed properly though. Pasted in more code.

Comment: Please prepare your question completely, prior to posting it. Adding significant changes afterwards might render answer given so far ununderstandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be way overthinking this, and you may want to call your string reversal from `main`, instead of within `getttheline` to make the original `line` available back in `main` instead of as a transient bit of input in `getttheline`. It's up to you.

Your `getttheline` function really need only read a line (terminated by either `'\n'` of `EOF`) from `stdin`. You are already passing `length`, why not pass the ***address of*** `length` (e.g. `&length`, and make the parameter `int *`) to make the final length of the string available back in the calling function (`main` here). For example, all you need to read a line of input from `stdin` is:

```
void gettheline(int *length, char *line)    
{
    int c = 0;
    *length = 0;

    while (*length + 1 < MAXLENGTH && (c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        line[(*length)++] = c;
    line[*length] = 0;        /* nul-terminate */

}
```

Above you use the value stored at the address pointed to by `length` as your counter to validate you do not store more than `MAXLENGTH - 1` chars in `line` (preserving space for the *nul-terminating* character). You simply read each char with `gethar()` until the `'\n'` or `EOF` is encountered, at which point you end the read loop and affirmatively *nul-terminate* at `length` chars (since you initialize `line` to all `zeros`, it is already done, but it is good practice to ALWAYS **affirmatively nul-terminate your strings**.

As for your reversal in place, all you need is a *start* and *end* pointer to `line` (which you have by virtue of having `length`), then you can very efficiently reverse the string in-place by swapping characters beginning at each end and working toward the middle -- swapping 2-chars per iteration, e.g.

```
/** strreverse - reverse string given by begin and end pointers.
 *  Takes valid string and swaps src & dest each iteration.
 *  The original string is not preserved.
 *  If str is not valid, no action taken.
 */
void strreverse (char *begin, char *end)
{
    char tmp;

    if (!begin || !end) {  /* validate both begin and end pointers */
        printf ("error: invalid begin or end pointer\n");
        return;
    }

    while (end > begin)
    {
        tmp = *end;
        *end-- = *begin;
        *begin++ = tmp;
    }
}
```

Putting all the pieces together in a short `main` that outputs both `line` and its reversal, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void gettheline (int *length, char *line);
void strreverse (char *begin, char *end);

#define MAXLENGTH 1000

int main (void)
{
        int length = 0;
        char line[MAXLENGTH] = "";  /* declare & initialize to zeros */

        gettheline (&length, line); 

        if (length) {
            printf ("line: %s  (%d chars)\n", line, length);
            strreverse (line, line + length -1);
            printf (" rev: %s\n", line);
        }
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line length is zero.\n");

        return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "my dog has fleas" | ./bin/strrevgetchar
line: my dog has fleas  (16 chars)
 rev: saelf sah god ym
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Sure, the goal it to help you become proficient in C. And the key to learning C is simply to *slow down*. There is a lot to take in. Take it step by step, always compile with *warnings enabled* in your compile string (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`) and do not accept code until it compiles cleanly without any warning. (you can learn a whole lot of C, just by paying attention to what the compiler is telling you and taking the time to understand *"why?"*). Good luck with your coding.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

In your source code, you pass a length of 0, which creates an array of 0 characters.

For printing and reversing also take into account the terminating zero at the end of the string. You do not want the terminating zero ending up at the beginning of your string. This will cause `printf` not to print anything.

Comment: You can pass `MAXLENGTH` as `length` and you are still not going to print anything....

Comment: Correct but it is also good if he tries for the learning effect, so my answers are pointing in the right direction but are not intended to give the complete solution.

Comment: You guys keep at it, I have faith you will get him sorted out `:)`

Comment: @alk Because he has changed the code in the meanwhile.